# How can i get the list of reacted users JDA?

Tags: discord-jda

I am trying to make a bot that edit embed message after reaction added.
Specifically to addField to old embed with List of reaction users.

How can i get the list of reacted users?

I am using the latest version of the Discord JDA.

```
    public void onMessageReactionAdd(MessageReactionAddEvent e) {
        if (e.getReactionEmote().getName().equals("")) {
            if (!e.getUser().isBot()) {
                e.getChannel().retrieveMessageById(e.getMessageId()).queue(p -> {
                    if (p.getEmbeds().size() > 0) {
                        if (p.getEmbeds().get(0) != null) {
                            EmbedBuilder gameEmbedWithPlayers = new EmbedBuilder()
                                    .setTitle(p.getEmbeds().get(0).getTitle())
                                    .setDescription(p.getEmbeds().get(0).getDescription())
                                    .setThumbnail(p.getEmbeds().get(0).getThumbnail().getUrl())
                                    .setFooter(p.getEmbeds().get(0).getFooter().getText(), p.getEmbeds().get(0).getFooter().getIconUrl())
                                    .setColor(p.getEmbeds().get(0).getColor())
                                                              //help here
                                    .addField(" Players", REACTIONED USERS, false);

                            p.editMessage(gameEmbedWithPlayers.build()).queue();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: To avoid nested if branches you can use the && operator to merge them into one if

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [MessageReaction#retrieveUsers()](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageReaction.html#retrieveUsers()). You can get the MessageReaction by using [Message#getReactions()](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#getReactions()).

---

Example:

```
List<User> reactedUsers = new ArrayList<>();
for (MessageReaction reaction : msg.getReactions()){
    reactedUsers.addAll(reaction.retrieveUsers().complete());
}
```

Comment: complete() will only get up to 100 users. You should use one of the other methods provided by PaginationAction and you should avoid blocking code like this.

Comment: @Minn Im aware. This is just a simple example, I provided links to the javadocs of both methods for them to be able to understand it by themselves and use them however they see fit.